# PRAW missing files / libraries

Tags: python, api, reddit, praw

I made a python script and I have to build an .exe file from it. First I have tried the py2exe and I get this error

```
 Exception: Could not find config file in any of: [u'D:\\...path...\\dist\\library.zip\\praw\\praw.ini', u'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\praw.ini', u'praw.ini']
```

Adding praw.ini into the .exe folder fix the issue but I had to add htmlentitydefs.pyc into the library.zip generated by py2exe:

```
File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 46, in <module>
File "six.pyc", line 203, in load_module
File "six.pyc", line 115, in _resolve
File "six.pyc", line 82, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named htmlentitydefs
```

Finally my .exe can launch and execute but after inserting the login credentials (which are handled by the r.login() PRAW method) I get this:

```
 File "<decorator-gen-51>", line 2, in login
 File "praw\decorators.pyc", line 78, in wrap
 File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 1471, in login
 File "<decorator-gen-8>", line 2, in request_json
 File "praw\decorators.pyc", line 116, in raise_api_exceptions
 File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 622, in request_json
 File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 453, in _request
 File "praw\__init__.pyc", line 434, in handle_redirect
 File "praw\handlers.pyc", line 146, in wrapped
 File "praw\handlers.pyc", line 56, in wrapped
 File "praw\handlers.pyc", line 102, in request
 File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 596, in send
 File "requests\adapters.pyc", line 497, in send
 requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Using pyinstaller I get an Import error:

```
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a super late reply, but have you tried typing `configparser` instead?